# How to save a parsed JSON into mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, collections, resttemplate

I'm trying to insert a parsed JSON into MongoDB. The classes i'm parsing are these:

```
public class News {

    private int totalResults;

    public List<Article> articles;
    //getters and setters
```

article:

```
public class Article {

    private String author;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private String url;

    //getters and setters
```

And the JSON I parsed is this:

```
"totalResults": 5,
"articles": [
    {
        "author": "BBC News",
        "title": "Russia swaps prisoners with Ukraine - prosecutor",
        "description": "Oleg Sentsov was convicted in 2015 for plotting and carrying out attacks in a controversial case.",
        "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-49518616"
    },
etc etc etc, for 5 articles.
```

I have to make the save right after the parse, and this is the parsing code.

```
@Service
public class ParseService {

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public News parseFive() {

        final int COUNTER = 5;

        News news = restTemplate.getForObject("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=19acc3a371d145ecb37a093f9985ea21", News.class);

news.setArticles(news.articles.stream().limit(COUNTER).collect(Collectors.toList()));
news.setTotalResults(COUNTER);


return news;
}
```

The MongoDB connection and save code is this:

```
MongoClientURI connectionString = new 
MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString)
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("newsCollection");

collection.insertOne(new Document("" ,news));
```

The error:

> Fri Aug 30 11:28:13 CEST 2019 
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). 
>   Can't find a codec for class com.kdmforce.test.models.News.

If i simply try to pass news in the insertOne method, it is an error. How do i insert the full news parsed json into mongodb? note: i already can establish a connection with my mongodb database. I just need the code for the insert. Thanks all for the effort!

Comment: Can you post here the error you get? Which driver are you using?

Comment: my friend edited the code, as we are cooperating on the same project. i added the code that makes connection and saving on the db and the error "cant find codec". my friend just tried to search for "how to create a codec" but looks like it doesnt work. do i have to transform the parsed json into Document or.... ? or do i have to implement the codec creations in the code? @lmarx thanks for your time